# How to return a new Bundle in react native when app resumes

Tags: android, react-native

I want to receive an Image path when the app resumes. I am new to react native and I don't know much java for android. I am receiving Image path when my app is not in the background, but I am not receiving the new image path when the app resumes,
Here is the code in MainActivity.java

```
    package com.myN;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;

//try
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.net.Uri;
import java.io.InputStream;
 
import java.io.File;
 
import android.database.Cursor;
 
import android.provider.MediaStore;
 
import com.facebook.react.ReactRootView; //change
//try


public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
 

   
  private ReactRootView mReactRootView; //change
  @Override
  protected String getMainComponentName() {
    return "myN";
  }

  //try
 @Override
    protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
        return new ReactActivityDelegate(this, getMainComponentName()) {
           
            @Override
            protected Bundle getLaunchOptions() {

                Intent intent = MainActivity.this.getIntent();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                Uri imageUri = intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
                 
 

                if (imageUri != null ) {
                    bundle.putString("image", imageUri.toString());
                    return bundle;  //returning bunble containing image 
                }else{
                    bundle.putString("image", "");
                    return bundle;
                      }
                
                }
 
        };

    }

  //try
  

  @Override
  public Bundle onResume() {
      super.onResume();
      
      
           //what should be the code here to return new bundle which consist of new Image path
  }
  
}
```

This is the code in my Manifest file

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Now, when I share an image from the gallery, I am receiving the image prop with initial props (when the app starts) and can be accessed as this.props.image and I am getting this

```
content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/38
```

But the problem is, I am not receiving a new Image path when I again share an Image from the gallery (the rn app is background), I am receiving the same prop (same Image filePath when the app resumes) as before although I have shared a new Image with the rn app.
I have read the documentation [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/communication-android#passing-properties-from-native-to-react-native), but I not able to understand where to write for the new props.

Comment: I have found a workaround but it is not about returning a new bundle, I found a package `react-native-share-extension` this worked like a charm [link](https://github.com/alinz/react-native-share-extension)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much idea about returning a new updated bundle, but you can try in activity in Manifest file

```
android:launchMode:"standard"
```

It will solve your problem of not receiving the new prop

Comment: It worked thanks but Now it is creating new instance of my app, what should I do now?